# Left join returning duplicate rows when there is match between two tables and match is not null

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

I am trying to join two table using left join on following tables

**Account Table**

```
Zone   ACC_NUM   Profile Status 
INT    123456    11      Active
DOM    246810    12      Active
INT    135791    12      Inactive
```

**Meter Table**

```
Acc_Num  Meter
123456   156894
135791   NULL
```

**Expected Result**

```
   Zone   ACC_NUM   Profile  Status    Meter
    INT    123456    11      Active    156894
    DOM    246810    12      Active    NULL
    INT    135791    12      Inactive  NULL
```

I have written the following query, but I see some duplicates like the results that followed the below query

```
Select a.Zone, a.Acc_Num, a.Status, m.Meter 
From Account a
left join Meter m on m.Acc_Num=a.Acc_Num
```

I got the following results which are not desirable

```
    Zone   ACC_NUM   Profile  Status    Meter
    INT    123456    11      Active    NULL
    INT    123456    11      Active    156894     
    DOM    246810    12      Active    NULL
    INT    135791    12      Inactive  NULL
```

From above results, I found that when there is match between both the tables and meter is `not null` it returned duplicate row, one with `NULL meter` and other with actual value and seems like it's good when there is no match or when there is match but meter is NULL.

**May I know a better way to get the expected results?**

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `123456   NULL` in second table?

Comment: Your query is about the best way to do it. Check your data, you cannot get such results from the data you provided in your question.

Comment: @lad2025 Yes, I'm pretty sure it doesn't have NULL but how do I handle if just in case there is a NULL to get the expected results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid:

```
CREATE TABLE #Account(
   Zone    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL 
  ,ACC_NUM INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Profile INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Status  VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO #Account(Zone,ACC_NUM,Profile,Status) VALUES ('INT',123456,11,'Active');
INSERT INTO #Account(Zone,ACC_NUM,Profile,Status) VALUES ('DOM',246810,12,'Active');
INSERT INTO #Account(Zone,ACC_NUM,Profile,Status) VALUES ('INT',135791,12,'Inactive');


CREATE TABLE #Meter(
   Acc_Num INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Meter   VARCHAR(60) 
);
INSERT INTO #Meter(Acc_Num,Meter) VALUES (123456,'156894');
INSERT INTO #Meter(Acc_Num,Meter) VALUES (135791,NULL);


Select a.Zone, a.Acc_Num, a.Status, m.Meter 
From #Account a
left join #Meter m on m.Acc_Num=a.Acc_Num;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384419)**</kbd>

The problem is probably your data in `Meter` table. I guess you have additional row with `123456 NULL` value.

If you want only one value per group you can use:

```
Select a.Zone, a.Acc_Num, a.Status, m.Meter 
From #Account a 
left join (SELECT Acc_Num, MIN(Meter) AS Meter 
           FROM #Meter 
           GROUP BY Acc_Num) AS m on m.Acc_Num=a.Acc_Num
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/384422)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Your query is about the best way to do it. However, to answer your question **how do I handle if just in case there is a NULL to get the expected results?**, just add a NULL check to your join condition:

```
Select a.Zone, a.Acc_Num, a.Status, m.Meter 
From #Account a
left join #Meter m on NOT m.Meter IS NULL AND m.Acc_Num = a.Acc_Num;
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/384435/494295/).