# LEFT JOIN returns matching rows AND extra NULL rows in addition to valid NULL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My question is similar to this one: [Left join returning duplicate rows when there is match between two tables and match is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508147/left-join-returning-duplicate-rows-when-there-is-match-between-two-tables-and-ma)

However, I have validated that my right-hand table does NOT have any actual NULLs in it. Both tables are temp tables. Simplified, but nothing important left out:

I have one table (#temp_fac_datesx) with:

```
facility nvarchar
[Inventory Date] datetime
```

I have another table (#temp_covid_inventory ) with:

```
fac_abbrv nvarchar
date datetime
```

And many other columns.

The important part of my query is like this (inside of an INSERT INTO where the temp tables are created ahead of time using CREATE TABLE):

```
select
              f.facility [Facility Code]
              
              , m.the_start
              , m.the_stop

              , case 
                 when m.date is NULL then @current_start
                 else CAST(Convert(date, m.date) as DateTime) 
              end as [Inventory Date] 

              , m.[createdAt] as last_entry_date
             from #temp_fac_datesx f
              left join #temp_covid_inventory m on f.facility = m.[fac_abbrv]
                AND f.[Inventory Date] = m.date;
```

What I'm getting are rows where facility and date both match, and ALSO an extra row matching nothing, but with f.facility and all NULLS for the other columns.

For the dataset I'm using, there are 75 rows that match for a particular date in question, with just 1 legitimately missing, so that there should be 76 rows - 75 with all columns filled, and just one with the facility column filled and the other columns NULLs. But instead, I'm getting 151 rows back 75 matching/filled, plus 76 with facility and NULLS.

Why the duplicates? How do I avoid them?

Comment: Do you understand what a "left (outer) join" does? You are including all rows in f along with those that match in M. The null values you get are because the facility and inventory date from f have no match in m - all those NULL values are a product of the left join; apparently you have many rows in f that have no match in m. As for duplicates, that is caused by either incorrect join logic, duplicate rows in your source tables, or perhaps a misunderstanding.

Comment: Please include sample input and output data in your question rather than a big slab of text

Comment: @SMor, yes, I understand left joins. Perhaps you missed the part where I said I visually checked and I have 75 positive matches and JUST ONE that should be missing from the right side? I managed to get some SQL guys from another department to look at things and they say it all looks right. It's not like SQL Server doesn't get bug reports and release bug fixes, so maybe we found one. I didn't include it in my description, but this only takes place in a while loop. I think we're going to have to do something else.